# Get data from array comma seperated and other

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I am making a `str_replace` function for my mail program and I can't get something to work. I am currently using this code to replace the words:

```
$strSQL     = "SELECT * FROM NAW.VAAW";
$objQuery   = mysql_query($strSQL);
{
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))   

$Voornaam   = $objResult["Voornaam"];
$Achternaam = $objResult["Achternaam"];
$Adres      = $objResult["Adres"];
$Woonplaats = $objResult["Woonplaats"];

$string     = $_POST['naam'];

$vaaw       = array("(voornaam)", "(achternaam)", "(woonplaats)", "(adres)");
$vervang    = array("$Voornaam", "$Achternaam", "$Woonplaats","$Adres");

echo str_replace($vaaw, $vervang, $string);
}
```

The problem with this is that if I ever change a column name or add/delete a column then I will have to change my code to. I was wondering if there is a way to get the data from an array can be displayed to look like this line does now:

```
$vaaw       = array("(voornaam)", "(achternaam)", "(woonplaats)", "(adres)");
```

So something like:

```
$vaaw       = array("(1st value)", "(2nd value)", "(3rd value)", "(and so on)");
```

I am getting the column names with:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='Klant'
```

So long story short, is there a way to get the result of this query:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='Klant'
```

to look like this:

```
$vaaw       = array("(value1)", "(value2)", "(value3)", "(and so on)");
```

and

```
$vervang    = array("$objResult["value1"]", "$objResult["value2"]", "$objResult["value3"]","$objResult["and so on"]");
```

I haven't been able to find anything on any other sites/forums I have looked so if anyone know if there is some sort of function for this it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I completely understand what you're trying to accomplish. But take a look at this and see if this is what you're looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php

```
<?php
/* The users table consists of three fields:
 *   user_id
 *   username
 *   password.
 */
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
}
$dbname = 'mydb';
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die("Could not set $dbname: " . mysql_error());
}
$res = mysql_query('select * from users', $link);

echo mysql_field_name($res, 0) . "\n";
echo mysql_field_name($res, 2);
?>

The above example will output:

user_id
password
```

You could use a combination of mysqli_field_count and mysql_field_name to dynamically populate the array.  Basically, you'd determine the number of fields and then using a for loop, dynamically append items to the array using the index.

array(mysql_field_name($res, 0), mysql_field_name($res, 1));

Answer (score 1):

Probeer dit:

```
<?php
// Grab your mysql result in your $objectResult array as you did in your code, then do the following:

$body = 'Geachte (Voornaam) (Achternaam), welkom bij blablabla... ' . PHP_EOL;

foreach($objectResult as $key => $value) {
  $body = str_replcae('(' . $key . ')', $value, $body);
}

// The output would be something like: "Geachte Jan Janssen, welkom bij blablabla"
?>
```

So basically what this will do is search for key names that correspond to your database column names and replace them with their corresponding values.

Ideal for an e-mail system, just plain and simple ;)